# Order by date on two ngFor in Angular

Tags: html, angular, sorting, ngfor

I have two arrays gotten from two different APIs, each from a different database and ordered by date in a descending order. When I display them in the html, I want the 2 'ngFor's to be rearranged into descending order by date. Currently, the output will look like this

| Date | Content 1 | Content 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 Mar 2021 | contents from database 1 | contents from database 1 |
| 3 Mar 2021 | contents from database 1 | contents from database 1 |
| 3 Mar 2021 | contents from database 1 | contents from database 1 |
| 10 Mar 2021 | contents from database 2 | (empty) |
| 2 Mar 2021 | contents from database 2 | (empty) |

However, I want them to look like this

| Date | Contents | Content 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 Mar 2021 | contents from database 2 | (empty) |
| 5 Mar 2021 | contents from database 1 | contents from database 1 |
| 3 Mar 2021 | contents from database 1 | contents from database 1 |
| 3 Mar 2021 | contents from database 1 | contents from database 1 |
| 2 Mar 2021 | contents from database 2 | (empty) |

Is there a way to rearrange them or put the two 'ngFor's into a new 'ngFor' and order them again? Please advise or share any available resources I could look into, thanks.

================================================================

*Add-on info after edits*

Component TS:

```
import { APIService } from '.../api.service';

export class AppComponent {
  array1;
  array2;

  constructor( public service: APIService; ) { } 

  ngOnInit() {
      this.apiServiceGet1(),
      this.apiServiceGet2(),
  }

  //Service Call
  apiServiceGet1() {
     this.service.get1().subscribe(result => {
     this.array1 = result;
     })
  }
  apiServiceGet2() {
     this.service.get2().subscribe(result => {
     this.array2 = result;
     })
  }
}
```

Service TS:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
@Injectable()
export class APIService {
   constructor ( public http: HttpClient ) { }
   
   public get1(): Observable<Array<Data>> {
      return this.http
        .get<Array<Data>>("api_endpoint")
        .pipe(map(response => response))
   }
   public get2(): Observable<Array<Data>> {
      return this.http
        .get<Array<Data>>("api_endpoint2")
        .pipe(map(response => response))
   }
}
```

HTML:

```
<table>
   <th> 
      <td>Date</td>
      <td>Content 1</td>
      <td>Content 2</td>
   </th>
   <tr *ngFor="let data of array1">
      <td> {{ data.Date }} </td>
      <td> {{ data.Content1 }} </td>
      <td> {{ data.Content2 }} </td>
   </tr>
   <tr *ngFor="let data of array2">
      <td> {{ data.Date }} </td>
      <td> {{ data.Content1 }} </td>
      <td> {{ data.Content2 }} </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Im confused? Why use two ngFors at all? Just wait until all observables are complete for each API call (use a forkJoin). Then add and sort all of those into one array. You should only be using one ngFor here.

Comment: I see, let me look into forkJoin, Im pretty new to Angular thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, think this is what you are looking for as an Example.

```
export class AppComponent {
  joinedApiCall$: Observable<Array<Data>>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.joinedApiCall$ = forkJoin(
      this.apiServiceGet1(),
      this.apiServiceGet2(),
    ).pipe(
      map(([first, second]) => {
        const unsorted = [...first, ...second]; // Merge two arrays
        return unsorted.sort((a, b) => b.Date - a.Date);
      })
    );
  }


  // Mock Service Call
  apiServiceGet1(): Observable<Array<Data>> {
    return of([
      {
        Date: 5,
        Contents: "contents from database 1"
      } as Data,
      {
        Date: 3,
        Contents: "contents from database 1"
      } as Data,
      {
        Date: 1,
        Contents: "contents from database 1"
      } as Data,
    ]);
  }

   // Mock Service Call
   apiServiceGet2(): Observable<Array<Data>> {
    return of([
      {
        Date: 10,
        Contents: "contents from database 2"
      } as Data,
      {
        Date: 2,
        Contents: "contents from database 2"
      } as Data
    ]);
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div *ngIf="this.joinedApiCall$">
  <div *ngFor="let data of this.joinedApiCall$ | async">
    <ul>
      <li>{{ data.Date }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the use of 'myOnlyArray' here? just curious

Comment: dont need it, updated:)

Comment: tq! i missed out 'async' in the beginning, then only i realized it's needed to work, nvr know abt that before